# modify python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Using python pandas how can we change the data frame

- input

  ```
  id1 AAA 12
  id1 BBB 2
  id2 DDD 3
  id2 AAA 23
  id3 FFF 34
  id3 AAA 5
  id3 BBB 65
  ```
- output

  ```
      id1 id2 id3
  AAA  12  23   0
  BBB   2   0  65
  DDD   0   3   0
  FFF   0   0  34
  ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the pivot_table function is what you are looking for.

```
row = [["id1", "AAA", 12],["id2", "BBB", 2],["id3", "CCC", 1],["id1", "BBB", 4],["id2", "AAA", 1],["id3", "AAA", 3]]
df=pd.DataFrame(row, columns=["id", "letters", "numbers"])
df.pivot_table(values="numbers", index="letters",columns="id").reset_index()
```

It does what the pivot table in excel does, summing the values in case the index is duplicated (but you can set the aggregating function to be an average)

Answer (score 1):

You can use unstack() and fillna() to get your expected output.

```
from pandas.compat import StringIO as pStringIO

new_data = pStringIO("""id Symbol Value
id1 AAA 12
id1 BBB 2
id2 DDD 3
id2 AAA 23
id3 FFF 34
id3 AAA 5
id3 BBB 65""")

df = pd.read_csv(new_data, sep="\s+", index_col=[0,1], skipinitialspace=True)
df_soln = (df.unstack(level=0)).fillna(0)
print(df_soln)
```

giving you

```
       Value            
id       id1   id2   id3
Symbol                  
AAA     12.0  23.0   5.0
BBB      2.0   0.0  65.0
DDD      0.0   3.0   0.0
FFF      0.0   0.0  34.0
```

If you don't want the Value top-level showing, just do the following.

```
df_soln.columns = [c[-1] for c in df_soln.columns]
```